# ssrs reports with user time display

Tags: sql, reporting-services

suppose report server is in Germany and user is in USA, now the user will generate report but with USA timing displaying in the report.

How to do it?

in the expression if I am using globals!executionTime, will it help or I need something extra

Comment: What about `System.TimeZone.CurrentTimeZone.ToLocalTime(globals!executionTime)`

Answer (score 0):

Set the `Language` property of the report to:

```
=User!Language
```

Then to display your dates and times you can use the [FormatDateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8aebkz6s%28VS.85%29.aspx) function with codes that will use the user's regional settings.